Internal system timer oscillations on modern computers - how big can it be?
When I synchronize two computers' system clocks up to 0.5 ms precision using NTP protocol implementation, it reports several tens of milliseconds skew in less than 10 minutes, and up to 3000 ms skew between them in 8 hours. Is it correct? Do they actually oscillate so much or am I doing anything wrong? I was expecting several milliseconds skew in 24 hours or so.

10 milliseconds in 10 minutes is about 17 ppm. That doesn't seem inconsistent. In 24 hours that would instead be about 100 ppb. And that would be unusual, I think.

Oscillations are generally periodic. Can you show what the variations are (+ and -) over time? An increasing divergence over time sounds more like a fixed or random discrepancy.

What operating system are you using? A decent OS will have a disciplined time service.

@TimWilliams there you go: ntp_resync_plot

Commercial-grade 100 ppm oscillators — the type used in most computers — can deviate from each other by about 1 second in 10,000. 60 ms in 10 minutes and 2.88 seconds in 8 hours is consistent with this.
Keeping to within 8 ms over 24 hours would require oscillators that have 0.1 ppm accuracy -- 3 orders of magnitude better.
NTP (and PTP) are meant to be run continuously to keep computer systems in tight synchronization.

Just to give the asker a feeling for what it costs to have a 0.1ppm oscillator: digikey tells us these basically start at 10€ a piece (you'll certainly get a better price if you buy a million, but that's the order of magnitude). In a time where a new retail mainboard costs 80€ incl taxes, that would, rule of thumb, mean ca 1/3 of the price of a computer mainboard. No sensible mainboard company could justify that expense for something that isn't requested by customers.

@MarcusMüller i didn't know anything about the ppm unit before i asked this question; i thought the very fact internal clocks operate at 100 MHz frequency already yields 1/10^5 ms error on each tick; appears i was wrong

A 25ppm (parts per million) difference in clock frequency means that after 1 hour (3600 seconds) the difference would be 90ms.
25ppm or 50ppm difference between two crystal oscillators would be of the typical order expected (worst-case will be worse that than by maybe 3:1) unless they are special (and expensive) ones designed for applications such as telecom.
So your numbers are in the expected range, without knowing more about the particular devices involved.
If you need closer synchronization you can sync more often (NPT aims at ~10ms) or consider using PTP (IEEE-1588) which can achieve continuous sub-microsecond synchronization.
Some comments on using PTP in networks that don't have PTP-enabled switches and so on here.

note that PTP needs your devices to be on the same timing-capable network; it doesn't work across the internet, or not-timing-designed ethernet segments.

and, even in telecom infra, you typically don't try to tightly synchronize the computer clock to the network clock; these two clock domains are simply kept independent. it's useful to somewhat keep the computer clock adjacent to the PTP-coordinated network clock mostly for logging timestamp reasons. Things like the oscillators for LOs and ADC/DACs in the radio heads of cellular networks are derived from the SyncE time distribution.

@MarcusMüller I believe it works, just not (nearly) as well if the switches etc. are not compliant. The use case I'm more familiar with is data acquisition. CERN did a bunch of work on it, and it was available open-source last I looked at this (the White Rabbit project).

Yep, I'm familiar with WR :) one of my clients uses it in their SDR devices, and people I cooperate with at a particle accelerator facility in Germany are using it for coordination of large-scale experiment sensors. But for WR, you need WR switches between nodes
